# zsh fails at path completition when command is vim

Tags: shell, vim, zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

When I try to autocomplete files (with vim as argument 0):

```
vim ~/.conf <TAB>
```

It shows:

```
_arguments:450: _vim_files: function definition file not found
_arguments:450: _vim_files: function definition file not found
_arguments:450: _vim_files: function definition file not found
```

It was working fine before!

Other commands:

```
cat ~/.conf <TAB>
```

give:

```
cat ~/.config/
```

Why is `zsh` failing only at `vim`?

Comment: Does it happen under `zsh -f` and then `autoload -U compinit && compinit` ?

Comment: No, it's fine then

Comment: It's working even after a `source .zshrc`.

Comment: Okay, you get to bisect your zsh configuration to figure out what's breaking it. Removing dreck like oh-my-zsh may help.

Comment: OK. So it fails when `source ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

Comment: Yet *another* "broken by OMZ" question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that removing all `~/.zcompdump` files solved it:

```
rm -r ~/.zcompdump*
```

Comment: this worked after I also ran `exec zsh` from James Kokou Gaglo's answer below

Answer (score 9):

This works for me :

`rm $ZSH_COMPDUMP && exec zsh`

Comment: This is the *correct* answer. The "accepted" answer will sometimes also work, but this is the _most correct_ answer. Works every time. :)

Answer (score 1):

None of these would work for me. My problem was antigen:

`rm ~/.antigen/.zcomp*`